# Is it ever advisable to use loginPopup or acquireTokenPopup in MSAL for a web app?

Tags: msal.js

According to the [MSAL documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-acquire-token?tabs=javascript), the redirect method is recommended if you want to support IE or if users have browser constraints or policies where pop-ups windows are disabled.

> You can't use both the pop-up and redirect methods in your
> application. The choice between a pop-up or redirect experience
> depends on your application flow:
>
> - If you don't want users to move away from your main application page during authentication, we recommended the pop-up method. Because the authentication redirect happens in a pop-up window, the state of the main application is preserved.
> - If users have browser constraints or policies where pop-ups windows are disabled, you can use the redirect method. Use the redirect method with the Internet Explorer browser, because there are known issues with pop-up windows on Internet Explorer.

Based on that, I can't imagine why anyone would want to use the popup experience since it may block users who have popups disabled from signing in. Seems like this is available only for web apps that are run in a very controlled environment. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One common reason to choose popups over redirects is that redirects can only be used in the top frame of your application. If your application is rendered in an iframe, popups are your only option for interactive auth. Besides that limitation, it's mostly a UX decision.